# How to create a generic method out of two similar yet different methods?

Tags: c#, generics, ado.net

I have two similar methods that basically does the same thing only with different objects.
What's the best way to make a generic method out of this if possible?

The two objects:

```
public class StoreObject {
  int Key;
  string Address;
  string Country;
  int Latitude;
  int Longitude;
}

public class ProjectObject {
  int ProjectKey;
  string Address;
  string Description;
}
```

The two methods that I potentially want to make into a generic:

```
public StoreObject GetStoreByKey(int key)
{
  using (DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities())
  {
    StoreObject so = new StoreObject();
    var storeObject = (from s in dbe.StoreTables
                       where s.Key == key
                       select s).First();

    so.Key = storeObject.key;
    so.Address = storeObject.address;
    so.Country = storeObject.country;
    so.Latitude = storeObject.latitude;
    so.Longitude = storeObject.longitude;

    return so;
  }
}

public ProjectObject GetProjectByKey(int projectKey)
{
  using (DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities())
  {
    ProjectObject po = new ProjectObject();
    var projectObject = (from p in dbe.ProjectTables
                       where p.ProjectKey == projectKey
                       select p).First();

    po.Key = projectObject.p_key;
    po.Address = projectObject.p_address;
    po.Description = projectObject.p_description;

    return po;
  }
}
```

I must note that:
- I have no control over how the table fields are named (ie. p_description).
- StoreTable in the DB, for example, may have other properties (like telephone, postal code, etc) but I'm only interested in showing what I've shown in the code.
- The same goes for the ProjectTable.

Comment: Those methods aren't similar. Almost every line is different. You could pass in an Expression as the where clause, but that would only make things more complex. Each of those methods knows exactly how to treat the object they deal with. I think it's abstracted about as much as it's going to get.

Comment: Well I'd have to argue that there are similarities, and while I agree that it is already abstracted, I figured I'd try asking in case some other people might have an idea to make it even more so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the tricky part is that your entities have different properties, so using generics to populate the different properties within one method will not be worth it. But you can return the whole object and then just use the properties you are interested in.

```
public T GetEntityByKey<T>(int key)
{
  using (DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities())
  {
    return = dbe.StoreTables.Set<T>.Find(new object[] {key});
  }
}
```

And to use it

```
StoreObject so  = GetEntityByKey<StoreObject>(123);
if(so != null)
{
    int lat = so.Latitude;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input, but I'm going to have to go with Steve's answer for this one. (I'll need to change some stuff though since I'm not only getting stuff from the StoreTables)

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed abstract out the type returned, and factor the `using`, but for the rest you'd need either a switch on the type requested or, reflection to pass in the fields to retrieve as parameters and the DB query to use.

The former would be bad practice and brings little to the equation, and the latter is costly and can get messy.

This is not really a good candidate for generics, unless you have many of such look-alike methods, in which case I'd go for the reflection approach.

HTH,

Bab.

Comment: I have considered reflection, but I figured I'd try to see if it's possible to do this as a generic.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that this is your entire 'unit of work' and thus the use of a fresh `DBEntities()` context in each of these methods is probably the root of your problem here.

Creating a `Repository` class that includes an instance of the `DBEntities` class for a single web request (or whatever other unit of request you have in your application) and which has these methods in it would be a better approach to eliminating the duplicate code here.  The scope of the `using()` is then outside these methods and hopefully tied to your web request or other unit of time.

As an option instead of creating a new class you could also extend the `DBEntities` partial class to include methods like these (assuming this is generated code).

Comment: Good idea, but I still want to try turning these into a generic.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have two different functionalities in each method:

1. Query an entity
2. Map that entity to another type

The first part has been addressed by Steve Mallory.

For the second part, you can use a mapper framework to handle copying values from one instance to another. Since the names of each type do not match, you'll need to tell it how to map names (in your example, adding "p_" and making it lowercase). One possibility would be [Emit Mapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customization%20using%20default%20configurator&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#Names_matching).

If you *were* to factor out all commonality, it would be something like:

```
public TResult GetById<TResult, TEntity>(int id)
{
    using (DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities())      
    {        
        T result = dbe.StoreTables.Set<T>.Find(new object[] {key});
        var mapper = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance
            .GetMapper<TEntity, TResult>(
               new DefaultMapConfig().MatchMembers((m1, m2) => "p_" + m1.ToLower() == m2));

        return mapper.Map(result);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll consider this, but it might just be simpler to map the three fields manually.